# Triples of positive integers $\left(a,b,c\right)$ such that $c^2=a^2+b^2+K$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request

What is known about triples of positive integers $\left(a,b,c\right)$ such that $c^2=a^2+b^2+K$, where $K$ is a nonzero constant with small absolute value? $K=0$ leads to the set of Pythagorean triples. I'm particularly interested in the case $K=1$ (points with integer coordinates on a two-sheeted hyperboloid $z^2=x^2+y^2+1$, e.g. $\left(2,2,3\right), \left(4,8,9\right), \left(12,12,17\right), \left(6,18,19\right), ...$).

Comment: I suspect there is just one tree  out of the root $(0,0,1)$  as $x^2 + y^2 + 1 = z^2,$  along with negating any entries, and the automorphism  $$ (x,y,z) \mapsto (x+2y+2z, 2x+y+2z, 2x+2y+3z) $$

Comment: Examples $$ (2,-2,3) \mapsto (4,8,9) $$ $$ (2,2,3) \mapsto (12,12,17) $$   $$ (4,-8,9) \mapsto (6,18,19) $$    $$ (4,8,9) \mapsto (38,34,51) $$     To go backwards  try negating the third, $$ (38,34,-51) \mapsto (4,8,-9) $$

Comment: Another way to describe the integer solutions is $((u-v)/2,2w,(u+v)/2)$ with $uv=4w^2+1$. I’m not sure how this relates to Will Jagy’s suspicions.

Comment: Let $K$ be a nonzero integer. and $a,b,c\in\Bbb{Z}$ such that$$c^2=a^2+b^2+K,\tag{1}$$or equivalently$$a^2+K=c^2-b^2=(c+b)(c-b).$$This is a factorization of $a^2+K$ into two factors congruent mod $2$. Conversely, any factorization $a^2+K=uv$ with $u\equiv v\pmod{2}$ yields a solution to $(1)$ by setting$$b=\frac{u-v}2\qquad\text{and}\qquad c=\frac{u+v}2.$$If $a^2+K$ is odd then any factorization $a^2+K=uv$ is of this form. If $a^2+K\equiv2\pmod{4}$ then no factorization $a^2+K=uv$ is of this form. If $a^2+K=4M$ then any factorization $M=uv$ yields a factorization $a^2+K=(2u)(2v)$ of this form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your particular interest $K=1$, because of $1$ is a square you can use the general solution of the equation $a^2+b^2+c^2=d^2$ which is similar to the solution (without common factors)for Pythagorean triples and is given by the identity
$$(2xz)^2+(2yz)^2+(z^2-x^2-y^2)^2=(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2$$ so if you get a solution with $abc\ne0$ you have infinitely many solutions.

For example, a particular solution of $a^2+b^2+1=c^2$ is $(a,b,c)=(4,8,9)$ so taking $(x,y,z)=(4,8,9)$ you get the solution given by tehe equality $72^2+144^2+1=161^2$ and  you can take $(x,y,z)=(72,144,161)$ to get another solution and so on.